# Почему Equals TreeViewItem.Header выдает False?

Tags: c#, wpf, .net

Здравствуйте. Пытаюсь выполнить проверку в коде на совпадение строк TreeViewItem.Header и textBox.Text, tvi.Header содержит букву А, и введенное слово в textBox содержит букву А. Но Equals все время принимает значение false, а должно быть true. С буквой Б проверка работает, а с А почему-то не работает, не пойму почему. В чем ошибка?

```
TreeViewItem tvi = tv.SelectedItem as TreeViewItem;

string Bukva = textBox1.Text;

if(tvi.Header.ToString().TrimEnd().Substring(0, 1).Equals(Bukva.ToString().Substring(0, 1).TrimEnd()))
```

Answer (score 2):

Проще сравнивать без Equals, просто ==  А насчет А и Б - А может быть как русской так и английской, что с Б немножко проблематично))
код сравнения 1 буквы нужно написать так:

```
string tvtext = tv.SelectedItem.Header.ToString();
string tbtext = textBox1.Text;
//код для защиты от ошибки при пустых строках
if (tvtext.Lenth < 1 || tbtext.Lenth < 1) throw new Exception();
if (tvtext[0] == tbtext[0]) { } else { }
```

Кстати, возможно нужно привести строки к верхнему или нижнему регистру, чтобы избежать сравнения по регистру, для этого есть функция строки

```
.ToUpper() .ToLower()
```

Comment: Все равно выдает false на А, на Б работает. Русская буква а и слово начинается с русской буквы А. Например слово Абрикос, и Header TreeViewItem A 

TreeViewItem xzvxz = tv.SelectedItem as TreeViewItem;
            string tvtext = xzvxz.Header.ToString();
            string tbtext = textBox1.Text;

            //код для защиты от ошибки при пустых строках
            if (tvtext.Length < 1 || tbtext.Length < 1) throw new Exception();

Comment: if (tvtext[0] == tbtext[0]) 
            {

                MessageBox.Show("True");
            }
            else if (tvtext[0] != tbtext[0])
            {

                MessageBox.Show("False");
            }

Comment: С английский раскладкой работает, как сделать то же самое с русской?

Пробовал задавать культуру в приложении но все равно с русской не работает.

Comment: приду домой, постараюсь разобраться. Видимо, что-то не так в System.Text.Encoding.